# LISP Xpath fetch multiple nodes in order

Tags: xpath, lisp, common-lisp

First of all, I'm really new to LISP and I'm trying to feel the language.

Lets supose the following code (I'm using closure-html and cxml-stop):

```
(defparameter *document*
   (cxml:parse "<test a='1' b='2' xmlns:foo='http://foo'>
                      <child>hello world</child>
                      <mommy>hello</mommy>
                      <father>world</father>
                      <child>hello world2</child>
                      <mommy>hello2</mommy>
                      <father>world2</father>
                      <child>hello world3</child>
                      <mommy>hello3</mommy>
                      <father>world3</father>
                      <foo:child>bar</foo:child>
                    </test>"
           (stp:make-builder)))
```

How I could do to fetch the followind output:

```
 Child: hello world
 Mommy: hello
 Father: world
 Child: hello world2
 Mommy: hello2
 Father: world2
 Child: hello world3
 Mommy: hello3
 Father: world3
```

I already was able to gel all Childs in order and then all Mommys in order and then all Fathers.

But I could not till now fetch the nodes in the order that they appear.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: XPath could be something like `//*[local-namespace='']` ... no idea about LISP part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know LISP, but if you're looking for XPath expression to get all child, mommy, and father elements inside test element, you can use this :

```
/test/*[name()='child' or name()='father' or name()='mommy']
```

The expression above means select all child element of `<test>` having element name equals 'child' or 'father' or 'mommy'. That will return all matched elements in order they appear in XML. Assuming you know how to call XPath expression in LISP, above XPath should give you idea to achieve that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know well the XML part and I'm not familiar with cxml's API.

As far as I understand, the problem is to wrap stp:of-name into somethin that would allow to search by multiple names.

One solution is to implement a function `of-names`:

```
(defun of-names (&rest names)
  #'(lambda (ch)
      (some #'(lambda (n)
                (funcall (stp:of-name n) ch)) names)))
```

Another solution is to implement a 'higher-order `or`', i. e. to write a wrapper for `or` that would take several functions of one argument and return a function that `or`s their values:

```
(defun f-or (&rest funs)
  #'(lambda (x)
      (dolist (f funs)
        (let ((y (funcall f x)))
          (when y
            (return y))))))
```

Now both forms

```
(let ((name-text (mapcar #'(lambda (e)
                             (list (stp:local-name e)
                                   (stp:data (first (stp:list-children e)))))
                         (stp:filter-children (f-or (stp:of-name "child") 
                                                    (stp:of-name "mommy")
                                                    (stp:of-name "father"))
                                              (first (stp:list-children *document*))))))

  (format nil "~{~{~@(~A~): ~A~}~^~%~}" name-text))

(let ((name-text (mapcar #'(lambda (e)
                             (list (stp:local-name e)
                                   (stp:data (first (stp:list-children e)))))
                         (stp:filter-children (of-names "child" "mommy" "father")
                                              (first (stp:list-children *document*))))))
  (format nil "~{~{~@(~A~): ~A~}~^~%~}" name-text))
```

yield the string

```
"Child: hello world
Mommy: hello
Father: world
Child: hello world2
Mommy: hello2
Father: world2
Child: hello world3
Mommy: hello3
Father: world3"
```